# Getting TypeError when makemigration to a model when using Django

Tags: python, django

I am currently learning Python from the book "Python Crash Course" by Eric Matthes. I am trying one of the assignments and am currently stuck. Can't figure out why this error appears.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Pizza(models.Model):
    """List of pizzas"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model"""
        return self.name

class Topping(models.Model):
    """Toppings"""
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model"""
        return self.name
```

Getting the error when I add the model Topping to the code.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel Tee\Desktop\pizzeria\pp_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Samuel Tee\Desktop\pizzeria\pp_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Samuel Tee\Desktop\pizzeria\pp_env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel Tee\Desktop\pizzeria\pp_env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Samuel Tee\Desktop\pizzeria\pp_env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Samuel Tee\Desktop\pizzeria\pizzas\models.py", line 12, in <module>
    class Topping(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Samuel Tee\Desktop\pizzeria\pizzas\models.py", line 14, in Topping
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

Comment: on_delete is a mandatory parameter that you need to provide. Add `on_delete=models.CASCADE` parameter to `pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza)`

Comment: @OP: while all the answers advising you to provide the on_delete attribute are technically correct, please don't blindly use the recommended models.CASCADE. Think about what your data model needs, even if this is just for the sake of a tutorial. Deleting all toppings that reference one specific pizza when that pizza is deleted might not be reasonable. Actually, referencing pizza models in the toppings already seems .. strange .. oh well. [on_delete](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `on_delete` to `pizza` ForeignKey.

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    """Toppings"""
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`on_delete` is required in Django 2 - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#features-removed-in-2-0:

> The on_delete argument for ForeignKey and OneToOneField is now
>   required in models and migrations. Consider squashing migrations so
>   that you have fewer of them to update.

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from the foreign key which should be defined as follows:

```
pizza = models.ForeignKey('Pizza', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```